# Why node.js memory leak when restart redis

Tags: node.js, v8

If you run below code, and restart you redis server, you will got one or two uncaughtException, but no more errors any more, and then, the memory will growing very fast, I want to know why and how to resolve this problem.

```
/**
 * This code will memory leak, if you restart redis server when the node process is running
 * 
 * @author Gui Lin
 */
var redis = require('redis').createClient();

setInterval(function(){

  redis.multi()
    .zrangebyscore('timeup', 0, Date.now())
    .zremrangebyscore('timeup', 0, Date.now())
    .exec(function(err, data) {
          if(err) console.log(err.stack);
          if(data) data = data[0];
      });
}, 1);

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably `node_redis` queuing up the commands in it's `offline_queue`. You can check `redis.offline_queue.length`, and perhaps stop issuing commands whenever that grows too large, or something like that. See also [node_redis documentation](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) (search for `offline_queue`).